# Autosys job to auto-update itself as SUCCESS if no response from CMD

Tags: autosys

In my Autosys box scheduled to run every week, I have 2 jobs:

- Job1 - Call up a shell script to generate a file
- Job2 - Call up a
  shell script to transfer the generated file

What happened is that for Job2, even though the file has been successfully transferred, there is no exit code from the shell script. **This resulted in Job2 and the box being in RUNNING state and prevent the box from running at the next week schedule.**

The ideal way is to amend the transfer shell script (in Job2) to return a proper exit code. But I do not have access to the shell script to make any change.

In JIL, is it possible to achieve either one of the following:

1. immediate after Job2 CMD execution, mark Job2 as success, OR
2. after X minutes of Job2 CMD execution, mark Job2 as success

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **term_run_time** attribute to the JIL of Job2 will terminate the job if it has been running for more than the number of minutes specified.

For example, **term_run_time: 60** sets a 60 minute termination timer.